# setOnClickListener for button is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listener

```
public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button mTrueButton; 
private Button mFalseButton; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
   mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.false_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }
});

    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button); 
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.false_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The emulator is able to show the buttons when I comment out the section of the code without the mTrueButton.setOnClickListener and the mTrueButton.setOnClickListener. However, when I place them back in, even without any methods inside the onClick(View v), the emulator tells me that QuizApp has stopped. There is nothing wrong with the import statements as I have used command + shift + o . Do anyone of any idea why it is not working?

Here is the fragment_quiz.xml class:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "match_parent"
android:gravity = "center"
android:orientation = "vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/false_button"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text = "@string/false_button" />

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what the first few lines of LogCat give me :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.geoquiz, PID: 1099
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geoquiz/com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat.

Comment: The code at the end of onCreate (starting with `if (savedInstanceState == null) {`) seems to be leftover from the Eclipse template. Is that supposed to still be there?

Comment: You could try to use `android:Clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="methodToBeCalled"` in your XML for the button as an alternate solution.

Comment: Can you debug the code and see where the error is occurring? A nullPointerException should be pretty straightforward to catch.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The error turned out to be setting the content view with the wrong file.

Answer (score 2):

in your code your setting the content view with

```
activity_quiz
```

and you said that the xml you posted is called

```
fragment_quiz
```

your getting a null pointer exception because the button your defining isnt in activity_quiz

Comment: your welcome, glad to be of assistance :)